# @IBDesignable UIButton Extension

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to extend the UIButton class by adding a cornerRadius property which can be changed at the design time without having to build the app. I am using the following extension class:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
extension UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius :CGFloat {

        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }

        set {

            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }

}
```

But when I make a change of the property cornerRadius in the Storyboard I do not see the change happening live! Am I missing something!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Extensions don't honor the IBDesignable qualifier. Only actual subclasses do. Annoying but true.

Comment: Maybe in the future we will get that functionality! It kinda sucks :(

Answer (score -7):

try this code:

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView {
     @IBInspectable var borderColor:UIColor? {
            set {
                layer.borderColor = newValue!.CGColor
            }
            get {
                if let color = layer.borderColor {
                    return UIColor(CGColor:color)
                }
                else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**this will show effect on runtime**

Comment: war does *this will show effect on runtime* mean? `@IBDesignable` & `@IBInspectable` are hooks for the interface builder. They are irrelevant during runtime.

Comment: mease bordercolor is not show in storyboard or nib, it will show when application running

Comment: Just trying to add clarity, While yes, your code would work during run-time, the question was around `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`, which are for marking views and properties which you can then interact with *at design time* via Interface Builder. And unfortunately, Interface Builder doesn't recognize those attributes when added to an extension. In other words, in your code example, `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` don't actually do anything. It works the exact same way if you remove them, or more accurately, *doesn't* work in Interface Builder.  Make sense?